# How to use multiple check-box values to work in a function and insert values in database

Tags: theme-development, php, customization, database, forms

I am working on a custom theme where there is option to upload images . I have certain check-boxes in the form which the users select as per where the image has to go. My form code is as follows :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="vtype[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="vtype[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="vtype[]" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="vtype[]" value="6" />
```

function for using the values is :

```
$image_category = implode(',', $_POST['vtype']);
```

if i echo this then the result is fine e.g. 3,4,5 . but if i try to use this value to insert values in database then the value is updated in only the 1st category and nothing happens for the remaining.

main function is inserting values in database is :

```
$post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $image_author, 
      'post_category' => array($image_category),
      'post_content' => $image_to_attach, 
      'post_title' => $image_title,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
    }
    // Insert the values in DB
    $id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

Comment: You are parsing a string as an `array($image_category)`? Isn't `$image_category` already an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing on this value:

```
'post_category' => array('3,4,5') // This is a single string
```

While you should be doing this:

```
'post_category' => array(3,4,5) // Three separate values
```

Don't forget to sanitize the POST values neither:

```
// Initialize categories
$post_category = array();

// Prevent "undefined variable" error notices
if (isset($_POST['vtype']))
{
  // Loop over selected categories
  foreach ((array) $_POST['vtype'] as $vtype)
  {
    // Validate vtype (only numbers allowed)
    if (ctype_digit((string) $vtype))
    {
      // Add category
      $post_category[] = (int) $vtype;
    }
  }
}

// Save the post with $post_category in database as you did before...
```

You can shorten this whole block to a oneliner as well, if you like. Just for fun:

```
$post_category = (isset($_POST['vtype'])) ? array_filter((array) $_POST['vtype'], 'ctype_digit') : array();
```

Comment: Thanks Geert that works great , one more thing i wud like to ask. Can i add more category ID to the code which is not the part of $_POST['vtype'].

Comment: @Harjeet: of course. It is a matter of adding values to the array, which can be done in many ways. Have a read in the PHP manual. `$post_category[] = 'new value';`

Comment: @Geert: i am completely lost at the moment , can you please let me know how can i add value for $_POST['ctype'] in the above code along with $_POST['vtype']. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Geert: i got the point i added $post_category[] = (int) $ctype; just below $post_category[] = (int) $vtype; and it worked. I hope this is the correct way to do it ....

Comment: @Harjeet: I'm not completely following anymore, but it seems you just need to polish your PHP array skills. ;) [Check out this tutorial](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/0/0).

Answer (score 0):

another way for submitting multiple values using checkbox, enjoy :)

`'day'=> $days

            );
    $format=array( '%s');
    $succes=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
    if($succes){
         echo 'Your values has been submitted';
    }
    else{
        echo "error in submitting";
    }
}`   


?>


    

            Day: 
            Any Day: 
            Sun: 
            Mon: 
            Tue: 
            Wed: 
            Thu: 
            Fri: 
            Sat: